# Endpoint x.x.x.x:port serving hashslot nnnn is not reachable at this point of time

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am using Stackexchange.Redis and trying to connect to a redis cluster and run HashGetAll(). But I'm getting an exception:

> Endpoint 172.18.0.2:6379 serving hashslot 4038 is not reachable at this point of time. Please check connectTimeout value. If it is low, try increasing it to give the ConnectionMultiplexer a chance to recover from the network disconnect.

I don't have errors when I work with my cluster via redis-cli. 
I am using windows and set up my redis cluster in Docker.

Here is how i connect to my db

```
var connectionMultiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(new ConfigurationOptions
{
    ConnectTimeout = 99000,
    EndPoints =
    {
      "127.0.0.1:6381",
      "127.0.0.1:6382",
      "127.0.0.1:6383",
      "127.0.0.1:6384",
      "127.0.0.1:6385",
      "127.0.0.1:6386"
    }
});
_database = connectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it. I was using multiple containers in my Docker with Redis instances, that I connected into cluster. There was some problem with configuration, I don't know what problem exactly, to fix my problem I used redis-cluster container, that has a pre-configured redis cluster.

Comment: were you able to find out what was wrong with your configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to restart docker with redis but it did not help.
Then stop problematic node at all, let master to change to another node and application apply change. After a few minutes when the error disappeared I have launched redis again and it started to work again.